# Are there multiple bits on a data cable at the same time?

Tags: cables, data

Let's say there is a copper under sea cable from New York to Lisbon with a length of 5350km.

Then a signal needs approx. *t = 5350km/c ≈ 19ms* to arrive.

Now let's imagine sending a file from New York to Lisbon.

I assume that you don't have to wait until one bit arrived before sending the next bit.

Because if you would have to wait you would have a speed of only *1000ms/19ms ≈ 53bit/s*.

So let's instead assume a speed of 1 MBit/s (still slow).
That would mean there are *19ms*1MBit/s = 19000* bits on the wire at the same time.

I did the same calculations with a standard LAN cable of 20m. With a speed of 10 MBit/s you can wait. But to get a speed of 100 MBit/s there must be multiple bits on the wire at one time.

Is that correct?

Comment: In the interest of accuracy, the propagation velocity of signals in copper cable is typically between 60% and 65% of the speed of light.

Comment: imagine downloading the images from the New Horizons satellite that flew by Pluto, which then transmitted the images at 100 bits per second to NASA's 3 huge dishes (Goldstone CA, Madrid, Canberra). About 10 hours of data were in transit thru the ether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like radio — when you're listening to an FM station at 100 MHz, the individual carrier waves are only about 3 meters long, so there are many hundreds or thousands of them "in flight" between the transmitter and you at any given moment.

Adding a copper wire transmission line does not really change this in any significant way.

Answer (score 5):

In general, if period of a single bit is smaller than the propagation delay through the medium, yes then there will be multiple bits in transit in the medium.